# Why is devise not displaying authentication errors on sign in page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm using rails 4.2

I have a helper file called devise_helper.rb

```
module DeviseHelper
    def devise_error_messages!
        return "" if resource.errors.empty?

    messages = resource.errors.full_messages.map { |msg| content_tag(:li, msg) }.join
    sentence = I18n.t("errors.messages.not_saved",
                  count: resource.errors.count,
                  resource: resource.class.model_name.human.downcase)

     html = <<-HTML
     <div class="row">
     <div class="large-12 columns">
        <div data-alert class="alert-box alert radius">
          <h4>#{sentence}</h4>
          <ul>#{messages}</ul>
        </div>
     </div>
     </div>
     HTML
     html.html_safe
  end
end
```

to customize error messages and it's working for registrations and passwords pages, but not for sessions pages. Why is this? I know that I can add something like this:

```
  <div class="row">
    <% if notice %>
      <div data-alert class="alert-box info radius">
        <%= notice %><%= link_to "X", '#', :class => 'close' %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <% if alert %>
      <div data-alert class="alert-box alert radius">
        <%= alert %><%= link_to "X", '#', :class => 'close' %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

To my application.html.erb file and error messages will display there, but I don't understand why I have to add that when I have the devise helper already.
For the passwords and registrations, I just had to add <%= devise_error_messages! %> but the sessions pages don't seem to work that way. I'm not sure if this is just how devise works or if there's something I'm missing.

**EDIT:**
I generated the sessions controller but I never changed anything in it since generating it. From what I understand, devise will just use its default controller until I change the one i generated. My passwords controller is like this as well. I did make some changes to the registrations controller to configure permitted parameters.

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

end
```

Comment: Could you please provide controller for your sessions? I wonder what your `create` action looks like

Comment: @TimKos see the edit above. I didn't change the create action so it should just be the devise default.

Comment: Wait, do you mean that no errors are rendered, or that the **customization** of error messages didn't work on those session views ?

Comment: @CyrilDD in the code I posted, I have all of that in my application currently, including the <% if notice %>... in application.html.erb and <%= devise_error_messages! %> in my view for sessions. When I submit a login form without any of the fields filled in, I don't get the customized error messages that I was expecting to get from <%=  devise_error_messages %>. Instead I get the customization listed in application.html.erb which is not what I would expect because none of the views for passwords or registsrations do this. My question is why is this only happeining in sessions?

Comment: Turns out the models are not validated for session#create ! See my other answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A login with blank/wrong fields **does not trigger (your) validations on the model**, and therefore won't show your validation errors !

if you debug with `byebug` (in the first line of your view for example), you'll notice

```
resource.errors.count # => 0
flash # => ....@flashes={"alert"=>"Invalid email or password."}
```

Devise populates the "alert flash" with specific sign in error messages unique to this context of sign-in.

Why do you not see all model validation error messages ? Because that wouldn't make sense : suppose your model has a mandatory `:gender` attribute with `validates_presence_of :gender`. If normal model errors were added, then you would also see "gender cannot be blank" in the list of errors when your user tries to sign in with a wrong login :oops:.

`devise_error_messages!` is a specific devise method meant to show those specific errors. You can think of it as a partial validation on the fields that are used for sign in (and that are defined in your devise config file)

**WORKAROUND :**

If you really want to show all your error messages, you could just explicitely run the validations :

at the beginning of `devise_error_messages!`

```
resource.validate # It will generate errors and populate `resource.errors`
```

I believe it shouldn't mess up with other actions that already work well (register, etc.)

Comment: Alright, I believe I understand why devise made this choice. Actually, if you validate the model, it will add every possible error, as it couldn't retrieve the user from the DB (eg : if you have a `validate_presence_of :gender` and you validate after a failed login, well, it's also gonna show an error `:gender=>"Can't be blank"` which is pretty pointless in the context of login ^^"

Comment: Thanks for being thorough. That's all I was really curious about, why it didn't have any errors and why devise debs would have designed that way.

Comment: @Henry maybe is right, those error messages are saved in the `flash` and not as `object` validations errors. Running `.validate` on the `resource` will not work for the wrong login authentication... also password will be cleared after unsucessfull  login attempt

https://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Controllers/SignInOut#sign_in-instance_method

some of my apps do not have this issue, but I was not able to figure out the reason

Answer (score 3):

For newer version of Rails/Devise I recommend:

Instead of `<%= devise_error_messages! %>` do:

```
      <% if flash[:alert] %>
        <%= flash[:alert] %>
      <% end %>
```

Your test may look something like this (note, you must make this a 'feature' functional test to have access to the "page" variable):

```
RSpec.feature 'Sign In', :type => :feature do

  describe "correct error message w/ wrong password" do
    before :each do
      @user = create(:user)
      @user.confirm

      visit new_user_session_path
      fill_in "user_email", with: @user.email
      fill_in "user_password", with: "wrongpassword"
      click_button "Log in"
    end

    it "tells user on page 'Invalid Email or password'" do
      expect(page).to have_text("Invalid Email or password")
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

When you ran `devise:install` (or something similar), it must have created views with some specific line of codes to display these messages.

If you look at [this link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Integrate-I18n-Flash-Messages-with-Devise-and-Bootstrap), they explain that you can add `<%= devise_error_messages! %>` in your views to display those error messages (which isn't really different from having a generic `<% flash.each {...} %>` somewhere in your HTML...)

Most likely, the views related to sessions do not contain this line of code.

Comment: I must politely disagree, once you add either `flash.each{...}` or `<%= devise_error_messages! %>` to **application.html.erb** these actions should be available in all of the rendered views. No need to specify them separately.

Comment: Oh my apologies, I didn't understand you had already added those lines of code in application.html.erb. Did you try to use a debugger/print the output of `devise_error_messages!` to make sure there's anything to render ?

Comment: No, I definitely have <%= devise_error_messages %> in my view for sessions.

Answer (score 0):

I like this way.
The HTML part is kind of original though.

I do not want to separate displaying error messages about authentication.
So, I'm using this way.

```
module DeviseHelper
  def devise_error_messages!

    flash_alerts = []

    if !flash.empty?
      flash_alerts.push(flash[:error]) if flash[:error]
      flash_alerts.push(flash[:alert]) if flash[:alert]
      flash_alerts.push(flash[:notice]) if flash[:notice]
      sentence = I18n.t("devise.failure.invalid") #=> "Invalid email or password."
    else
      sentence = I18n.t("errors.messages.not_saved",
                        count: resource.errors.count,
                        resource: resource.class.model_name.human.downcase)
    end

    return "" if resource.errors.empty? && flash_alerts.empty?

    errors = resource.errors.empty? ? flash_alerts : resource.errors.full_messages
    messages = errors.map { |msg| content_tag(:li, msg) }.join

    html = <<-HTML
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      <div id="error_explanation">
        <strong>#{sentence}</strong>
        <ul class="m-b-0 p-l-30 ">#{messages}</ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    HTML

    html.html_safe
  end
end
```