# devise show wrong email/password message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

My devise login page doesn't show wrong email/password message
How to show them?

What I've done:
I have generated devise views and controllers:

`rails generate devise:views`

`rails generate devise:controllers`

I have created `devise_helper.rb`

```
 module DeviseHelper
  def devise_error_messages1!
    resource.errors.full_messages.map { |msg| content_tag(:li, msg) }.join
  end

  def devise_error_messages2!
    resource.errors.full_messages.map { |msg| content_tag(:p, msg) }.join
  end
end
```

Also I show flash msgs in `views/users/sessions/new.erb`

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>

  # New code (allow for flash elements to be arrays)
  <% if msg.class == Array %>
    <% msg.each do |message| %>
      <%= content_tag :div, message, :id => "flash_#{name}" %>
    <% end %>
  <% else %>

    # old code
    <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" %>

  <% end %> #don't forget the extra end
<% end %>
```

What do I do next?
I have read similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31393915/why-is-devise-not-displaying-authentication-errors-on-sign-in-page) but the didn't help

upd: I found what was wrong, my answer is written below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I should just put this code

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>

  <% if msg.class == Array %>
    <% msg.each do |message| %>
      <%= content_tag :div, message, :id => "flash_#{name}" %>
    <% end %>
  <% else %>

    <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" %>

  <% end  #don't forget the extra end %>
<% end %>
```

Here:
`/home/direwolf/rails_projects/limo/app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb`

Comment: and no need for helpers and something else