# Rails error messages in login form with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I think I've got complicated problem but let's keep it simple. I'm using devise and I want to show error message below form in my login page. Right now when user provide wrong password in console I've got an error `POST 401 (Unauthorized)` but errors didn't showed up in a page.

**slice_code.js.erb**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var form = $('.centralized-login')
  form.submit( function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    var email = $('#email-input').val()
    var password = $('#password-input').val()
    var req = $.ajax('/user_role', {
    data: {
      email
    }
    })

    req.then( function(result) {
      var { role } = result
      switch (role) {
        case 'company_manager':
          $.ajax('/users/sign_in', {
            method: "POST",
            data: {
              "user[email]": email ,
              "user[password]": password,
              "authenticity_token": $('input[name="authenticity_token"]').val()
            },
            success: function(data, textStatus, req){
              window.location="/users/sign_in"
             }
            })
            break;
```

should I add something like `$("ajax:error")` ?

**_new.html.erb**

```
<div class="col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
  <div class="vr-textfield-wrapper">
    <%= f.email_field :email, id: "email-input", class: "vr-textfield", placeholder: t('users.passwords.new.email_placeholder'), required: true, aria_required: true, autofocus: true %>
    <span class="vr-field__invalid-msg"><%= t 'users.passwords.new.valid_email'%></span>

    <% if resource.errors.full_messages_for(:email).first %>
      <div class="vr-textfield-wrapper">
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
          <div class="error-explanation">
            <%= t('activerecord.errors.models.user.attributes.email.not_found_in_database') %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit**

```
        success: function(data, textStatus, req){
          window.location="/users/sign_in"
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          $('.centralized-login').find('.error-explanation').html(errorThrown)
          console.log(textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
        }
        })
```

**sessions_controller.rb**

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  include LogoutUsergroups

  def after_sign_out_path_for(_user)
    new_user_session_path
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can render the error in the js response(create.js.erb) of view file itself. something like below,

```
<%- if resource.errors.any? %>
   var id = $('form#Id') <!-- Replace with your selector -->
   <% resource.errors.each do |key, value| %>
     id.find('selector').html("<%= "#{key.to_s.humanize} #{value}" %>");
   <% end %>
<%- end %>
```

Or you could use the error function as like you used the success function,

```
$.ajax({
         success: function(data, textStatus, req){
          window.location="/users/sign_in"
         }           

         error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             id.find('selector').html(""); # Use the error here to show in the UI.
             console.log(textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
         }
      });
```

`$("ajax:error")` should be used when using the `remote: true` for form submit. For reference: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax

Comment: Ok what should I put in to line `id.find('selector').html(""); ` ? the `id` of this form? if I leave it with `selector` I've got `Uncaught ReferenceError: id is not defined`, if I change to `email-input` (this is an ID for email form) I will have the same error.

Comment: If you have any unique selector for form, you could try something like, 
`$('.centralized-login').find('.error-explanation').html(errorThrown)`

Comment: I add this line but now in the condole I have `401 (Unauthorized)` error plus `error Unauthorized` (which is from `console.log` I guess) and no error displayed under the form. I'm confused.

Comment: Updated - I'm using devise with small modification as you see

Comment: I think, `devise` by default doesn't respond with exact error messages(ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31393915/why-is-devise-not-displaying-authentication-errors-on-sign-in-page). Please watch this http://railscasts.com/episodes/210-customizing-devise?autoplay=true for customizing devise gem.